# Finding stabilizing average of agent-based model runs

Tags: excel

So I ran about 200 agent-based model runs and I want to see how the average is changing over time.

For example if we have 10 points

2 4 2 8 6 5 9 8 1 3

I want to calculate the average as the number of points changes

(2+4)/ 2 = 3
now for the next point it will be (3+2)/2 = 2.5

so I can plot each average and see after how many runs does the average stabilize. Something like this image < https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSVA7.jpg > Can someone provide an equation or method?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you want to take the average of the first two points =(P1+P2)/2 then take the average of this average and the next point, i.e. ((P1+P2)/2) +P3)/2 ?

Comment: Yes and so on until I get a stable average. The reason I am doing this is because in agent-based modelling the results are stochastic and have high randomness. So tend to run the same simulation a number of times depending on the complexity ( 10,20,30 100 or 500 more times). Then we take the average of the runs and that can be taken as a representation of the output. So I want to see after how many runs the average becomes stable and converge to a certain value just like the image in the link. X-axis is the number of runs and y is the value at which the parameter converges. I hope it helps!

Comment: I found an easy way by doing  =AVERAGE($B$23:D$23) and then dragging to the end. This way, if you look at the equation well, only the column letter will change and hence I can do it by dragging which saves time. I was wondering if there is an easier way because I have many tables. IF it is too much work for you @TomSharpe or others who will give it a try then leave it, I'll just do my way. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I may be able to help but I can't quite match your formula =AVERAGE($B$23:D$23) with the example in your question - for the first three points, the 'cumulative average' from the formula would  would just be (2+4+2)/3 = 2.67 , not 2.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a 'cumulative average' of 1,2..n points. You can do this in a single formula if you don't mind using [offset](https://chandoo.org/wp/offset-formula-explained/):

In most versions of Excel (F1):

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(B23,0,0,1,COLUMN(B23:K23)-COLUMN(A23)))
```

In Excel 365 only (F2):

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(B23,0,0,1,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(B23:K23))))
```

Or a more dynamic version that works for a whole row (F3):

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(B23,0,0,1,COLUMN(A1:INDEX(1:1,COUNT(23:23)))))
```

and (F4)

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(B23,0,0,1,SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(23:23))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You ! a *bit* too late but thank you very much !